# Display Static Block for a Customer Group

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, customer-group

I would like to place a static block for specific customer group on the header.phtml file. What is the customer group ID code to place with the block code below? For example the Customer Group ID is 4.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('test-banner-gen')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please check i have added answer hope it's work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below code to show static block for particular customer group if customer is logged In.

```
/* Check if customer is logged in */

        $isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
    /* If customer is logged in */

    if($isLoggedIn):
        /* Get the logged in customer's group ID */
            $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        /* Check if the logged in customer's group ID matches with the ID you are after */

        if($customerGroupId == 4):
            echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('test-banner-gen')->toHtml(); 
        endif;
    endif;
```